# How to reduce for loop speed

Tags: php, for-loop

i'm facing a big issue.  i need to generate exact 7 number combinations and i written a code for that by using 7 forloops and also it is working fine with very less numbers.Please check the attachment so you will be very clear what i need actually. 
Please provide PHP result.

```
<?php
// I need the combinations for this commented numbers   
// 1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 2, 8, 14, 20, 26, 32, 3, 9, 15, 
// 21, 27, 33, 4, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 5, 11, 17, 23, 29,
// 35, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36
$string=array(1,7,13,19,25,31,2,8,14,20,26,32,3,9,15,21,27,33,4,10,16,22,28,34);
$len=count($string);
$c=0;
ob_start();
for ($e = 0; $e < $len - 6; $e++)
{
   for ($f = $e+1; $f < $len - 5; $f++)
   {
       for ($g = $f+1; $g < $len - 4; $g++)
       {
           for ($h = $g+1; $h < $len - 3; $h++)
           { 
               for ($i = $h+1; $i < $len - 2; $i++)
               {
                   for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $len - 1; $j++)
                   {
                        for ($k = $j + 1; $k < $len; $k++)
                        {
                             $c++;
                             $output[] = $string[$e] . "," . 
                                         $string[$f] . "," . 
                                         $string[$g] . "," .  
                                         $string[$h] . "," . 
                                         $string[$i] . "," . 
                                         $string[$j] . "," . 
                                         $string[$k];
                             ob_flush();
                        }
                        ob_flush();
                   }
                   ob_flush();
               }
               ob_flush();
           }
           ob_flush();
   }
   ob_flush();
}
ob_flush();
}
echo count($output);
?>
```

And I need the output same like i mentioned below. 
Output:

```
passed numbers $string=array(1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 2, 8, 14) and the out put is below
count of combinations = 36
Array
(
    [0] => 1,7,13,19,25,31,2
    [1] => 1,7,13,19,25,31,8
    [2] => 1,7,13,19,25,31,14
    [3] => 1,7,13,19,25,2,8
    [4] => 1,7,13,19,25,2,14
    [5] => 1,7,13,19,25,8,14
    [6] => 1,7,13,19,31,2,8
    [7] => 1,7,13,19,31,2,14
    [8] => 1,7,13,19,31,8,14
    [9] => 1,7,13,19,2,8,14
    [10] => 1,7,13,25,31,2,8
    [11] => 1,7,13,25,31,2,14
    [12] => 1,7,13,25,31,8,14
    [13] => 1,7,13,25,2,8,14
    [14] => 1,7,13,31,2,8,14
    [15] => 1,7,19,25,31,2,8
    [16] => 1,7,19,25,31,2,14
    [17] => 1,7,19,25,31,8,14
    [18] => 1,7,19,25,2,8,14
    [19] => 1,7,19,31,2,8,14
    [20] => 1,7,25,31,2,8,14
    [21] => 1,13,19,25,31,2,8
    [22] => 1,13,19,25,31,2,14
    [23] => 1,13,19,25,31,8,14
    [24] => 1,13,19,25,2,8,14
    [25] => 1,13,19,31,2,8,14
    [26] => 1,13,25,31,2,8,14
    [27] => 1,19,25,31,2,8,14
    [28] => 7,13,19,25,31,2,8
    [29] => 7,13,19,25,31,2,14
    [30] => 7,13,19,25,31,8,14
    [31] => 7,13,19,25,2,8,14
    [32] => 7,13,19,31,2,8,14
    [33] => 7,13,25,31,2,8,14
    [34] => 7,19,25,31,2,8,14
    [35] => 13,19,25,31,2,8,14
)
```

Comment: You might want to actually explain what the purpose of your code is.

Comment: Yea explain in detail the purpose of your code, im almost positive there will be a better solution to this :/

Comment: I completely fail to see any possible connections between your topic, the description and your code example...

Comment: It looks like an attept to build a list of every single combination of 7 numbers from the array, then just to list how many there are. There's far more efficient methods than actually building the set.

Comment: I think it says "I want to generate all possible 7 number combinations from this list of 36 numbers."

Comment: @MJB The final output is only the count though

Comment: The final output can be calculated in a simple combinatorics equation, I can't remember exactly how to do it but you use Choose

Comment: this is a "give mhe the codez" question, it will be closed shortly unless it is revised.

Comment: This is the logic which i used for lotto. It is one of the  norwegien gambling game. these are all the number of combinations which will be generated using user betting numbers. Because the lotto result is exact 7 and i will match the 7 numbers in this combinations and take the winning combinations count and publish result for it . I think this will help you

Comment: Mate i need to generate an array for those combinations which you have got the count, I am already having the code to get number of combination and also to generate combinations for that count . My code is entirely correct however my code takes too long time to generate output for 36 numbers.so i need a solution to optimize this code or else any other simpler way to generate same output as my code does. Please check my latest edited Post . you will get an idea that what i am expected from the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is all for the lotto, then I still can't think of any reason to spew out a list of all possible combinations... other than because "you want to". If you want to display the winning combinations, then they're published when the draw is made.

Comment: I just want to generate combinations (not to print in a web page) and match the result with that . Is it possible to make the loops fast or else any other way to make it the same output in less execution time?

Comment: If you're doing this to (say) match with a user's selected numbers, there are probably still better ways to do it.  Is your ultimate goal really to *display* all of the combinations, or are you going to be doing something else with this data afterwards?

Comment: If you really have to have a page that displays every possible combination... run your script as a 1-off without worrying about how long it takes, writing the output to a CSV file (or whatever) that you can then use whenever you need to match against the full list of combinations. After all, the set of combinations doesn't ever change.

Comment: No my friend, the 36 numbers are not predefined. so it may vary depends upon the user selection. some might select 10 numbers  like for example (1,10,14,32,12,18,20,5,12,8) and some might above 10. But maximum numbers are 36. So the combinations will be different each time and i am not going to store these combinations . i am going to match the result(7 numbers) with these combinations and then i will take a count of matching combinations with the result 7 numbers and store in the database. now you all might have clear with this problem .

Comment: I still cannot see why you need every possible combination. Surely you only need to match the 7 number result with the 10 (or however many) numbers that the user has selected using array_intersect() or similar.

Comment: Hi mark, 
          Just forget about rest of the logic. My goal is to generate the combination as i posted above. I just mentioned example output array to make all understand that what i need. Generation of combination is mandatory in my project . you can run my code with short array example (1,5,9,10,32,18,7,3)(Note:array value must above 7 numbers, am i am not gonna print those arrays). Please help me to generate the combinations mark.

Comment: You realize that there will be 8.3 million combinations of 7 elements from a set of 36 numbers? PHP is not the language of choice for such operations... Unless you're willing to switch to a compiled language, this will take some time no matter how efficient your algorithm is.

Comment: -1 for being unwilling to take advice. People are trying to help you here, and you are ignoring their advice *and* taking their effort for granted.

Comment: My friends, i am not at all ignoring all your advice instead i am making you people to understand what i am facing currently. Hi mates i am using another technology with PHP is adobe flex 3. Is it possible to generate the same in flex?please suggest me . valuable suggestions are most invited

Comment: Yes it's possible to do generate the list if flex, or any other computer language; but with that many combinations it won't be noticeably faster.... have you tried any of the other methods that people have offered? And I still don't understand why you need to generate the list. For the matching, what's wrong with 

$userSelection = array(1,10,14,32,15,18,20,5,12,8);

$drawnResult = array(1,2,3,5,12,23,30);

$matches = array_intersect($userSelection,$drawnResult);

var_dump($matches);

Answer (score 8):

```
function factorial($factVal) {
    $factorial = 1;
    while ($factVal > 1) {
        $factorial *= $factVal--;
    }
    return $factorial ;
}

function permutations($numObjs,$numInSet) {
    return round(factorial($numObjs) / factorial($numObjs - $numInSet));
}

function combinations($numObjs,$numInSet) {
    return round(factorial($numObjs) / factorial($numObjs - $numInSet)) / factorial($numInSet);
}


$string=array(1,7,13,19,25,31,2,8,14,20,26,32,3,9,15,21,27,33,4,10,16,22,28,34); 
echo 'Number of Combinations = '.combinations(count($string),7).'<br />';
echo 'Number of Permutations = '.permutations(count($string),7).'<br />';
```

Comment: Hurrah for actual use of mathematics!

Comment: Hi mate i need the combination 7 numbers in array too. i need them for some other calculation. please help me out of this

Comment: @kamlesh What other calculation. Building the complete list is going to blow your memory pretty quickly, and there's almost certainly a better way of doing your other calculation

Comment: Mate i need to generate an array for those combinations which you have got the count, I am already having the code to get number of combination and also to generate combinations for that count . My code is entirely correct however my code takes too long time to generate output for 36 numbers.so i need a solution to optimize this code or else any other simpler way to generate same output as my code does. Please check my latest edited Post . you will get an idea that what i am expected from the code.

Comment: A few people have offered other algorithms to generate the various combinations.... but while some of these options might be faster than your loop, there is never a quick solution, and you will always have memory issues with that many combinations. You haven't given any explanation of _why_ you need to work out every possible combination, simply that you _want_ to do so; and I can't think of any valid business reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough i cant give you the complete code i can tell you that i've done this before even for higher combinations and you need to use **[RECURSIVE FUNCTIONS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function)** instead of using nested loops.

Recursive functions give you the flexibility to go beyond 7.

NLV

Comment: Mathematics gives you the ability to work with significantly higher than 7 from 36, and far faster than recursion

Comment: Mate i need to generate an array for those combinations which you have got the count, I am already having the code to get number of combination and also to generate combinations for that count . My code is entirely correct however my code takes too long time to generate output for 36 numbers.so i need a solution to optimize this code or else any other simpler way to generate same output as my code does. Please check my latest edited Post . you will get an idea that what i am expected from the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: What we are dealing here is permutations. As phimuemue said you may get several issues if the length of your combination grows. I think what Mark has given a good one. If you are dealing with higher combinations with greater length you need to add some rules which will eliminate bunch of combinations from the result thus increasing the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the combinations, you could do something like this...

- NOTE 1: This will only give you the ordered results, and no permutations.
- NOTE 2: If you only need the count, use Mark's answer.
- NOTE 3: This is not tested at all, so there might be some offset errors etc.

Here goes:

```
function combinations($set,$length) {
  $combinations = array();

  for($i = 0, $n = count($set); $i <= ($n - $length); $i++) {
    $combination = array();
    $combination[] = $set[$i];

    if($length > 1) {
      $combination = array_merge(
        $combination,
        combinations(array_slice($set,1+$i), $length-1)
      );
    }

    $combinations[] = $combination;
  }

  return $combinations;
}

$allCombinations = combinations($allYourNumbers, 7);
```

**Edit** Changed order of parameters to array_slice

Comment: Hi mate i am getting empty array when i print this and warning of
Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in G:\xampp\htdocs\pick1\lottocom.php on line 79

Comment: Wrong order of parameters to array_slice. Changed from offset,array to array,offset.

Comment: Mate i did all this but it comes empty array with some error. Please check my latest edited Post . you will get an idea that what i am expected from the code.

Comment: Hi mate. Help me to optimize the execution time please.

Comment: This recursive solution will probably not reduce your execution time, as there is more overhead and memory consumption involved. It is however cleaner and more flexible code (still not bugfixed though :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question right, but I think you want to generate all combinations of numbers in your array that can be obtained kindof "left to right", i.e. if we take a sorted array of numbers (let's say from 1 to 50) and the first number is already 4, then all following numbers shall be greater than 4, if the second number is 12, all following numbers shall be greater than 12, and so on.

So the fact is that the number of such combination of numbers is so large, that - whatever algorithm you use - at some array size, it is not tractable, i.e. it takes too long to really generate all the numbers, because they are just too many.

If you take `m` numbers out of `n` numbers, you have `binomial(n,m)` many possibilities to do so (where `binomial(n,m)` is the binomial coefficient of `n` and `m`).

So, for your case in particular `binomial(n,7)` is interesting. However, the binomial coefficient is a really fast growing function. I.e. if you make the parameters just a little bit larger, the result will be really much larger.

```
binomial(9,7) = 36
binomial(10,7) = 120
binomial(11,7) = 330
binomial(12,7) = 792
...
binomial(15,7) = 6435
binomial(20,7) = 77520
binomial(30,7) = 2035800
```

You see, for 30 numbers, there is already quite a bunch of possibilities, and it takes time to enumerate all of them. So, how clever your algorithm might be, at some point of array size it will have to give up just because the sheer amount of possibilities.

I wrote a little program in C:

```
#define PRINTITEMS 0

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _comb{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  int x3;
  int x4;
  int x5;
  int x6;
  int x7;
} comb;

void generateAll7Possibilities(int* a,int n, comb* target){
  int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7;
  int c = 0;
  for (i1=0; i1<n-6; i1++){
    for (i2=i1+1; i2<n-5; i2++){
      for (i3=i2+1; i3<n-4; i3++){
        for (i4=i3+1; i4<n-3; i4++){
          for (i5=i4+1; i5<n-2; i5++){
            for (i6=i5+1; i6<n-1; i6++){
              for (i7=i6+1; i7<n; i7++){
            target[c].x1=a[i1];
            target[c].x2=a[i2];
            target[c].x3=a[i3];
            target[c].x4=a[i4];
            target[c].x5=a[i5];
            target[c].x6=a[i6];
            target[c].x7=a[i7];
            if (PRINTITEMS){
              printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", target[c].x1, target[c].x2, target[c].x3, target[c].x4, target[c].x5, target[c].x6, target[c].x7);
            }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


int main(){
  printf("This is enumerator\n");
  int array[36];
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<36; ++i){
    array[i]=i;
    printf("%d\n",array[i]);
  }
  printf("Starting generation");
  comb* target= malloc(sizeof(comb)*8347680);
  generateAll7Possibilities(array,36,target);
  printf("Generation finished");
}
```

The above program runs just fine if you *do not* print the values. However, as soon as you start printing the values, you have no chance of getting finished.

So I suggest, that you try removing the output and just generating all possible combinations.

Comment: Yes your examples are correct. i need the combinations. not a count of combinations like this
 $string=array(1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 2, 8, 14) and the out put is below count of combinations = 36 Array ( [0] => 1,7,13,19,25,31,2 [1] => 1,7,13,19,25,31,8 [2] => 1,7,13,19,25,31,14 [3] => 1,7,13,19,25,2,8 [4] => 1,7,13,19,25,2,14 [5] => 1,7,13,19,25,8,14 [6] => 1,7,13,19,31,2,8 [7] => 1,7,13,19,31,2,14 [8] => 1,7,13,19,31,8,14 [9] => 1,7,13,19,2,8,14 [10] => 1,7,13,25,31,2,8 
.
.
.
.[35] => 13,19,25,31,2,8,14 )

Comment: You say that the output cunt is below the count of combinations. Could you explain why this should be so?
If you really want to print out all the subsets, that contain only elements right to the elements already in the subset, then that this is exactly the number of combinations, right?

Comment: No my friend, the 36 numbers are not predefined. so it may vary depends upon the user selection. some might select 10 numbers like for example (1,10,14,32,12,18,20,5,12,8) and some might above 10. But maximum numbers are 36. So the combinations will be different each time and i am not going to store these combinations . i am going to match the result(7 numbers) with these combinations and then i will take a count of matching combinations with the result 7 numbers and store in the database. now you all might have clear with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative methodology (not in PHP) that allows to determine the combination of an arbitrary combination in the set of combinations.

In a combination set, there are a finite number of different combinations.  This mean that each combination can be assigned a sequence number, and it is possible to convert the sequence number to the combination set.  The key piece is the following routine .... get_array_offset().

```
int get_array_offset (x, y) {
    int  offset = 0;
    while (1) {
        choices = choose (x, y);   // x choose y
        if (sequence <= choices)
            break;
        sequence -= choices;
        x--;
        offset++;
    }
    return offset;
}
```

Let us suppose we are dealing with a 24 choose 7 combination, and all our values are stored in the array

```
valueArray[24] = { ....};
```

For a given sequence number, to find the the first item in the combination is ...

```
sequence = ...;                     // sequence number in combination set
index = 0;
offset = get_array_offset (24 - 1 - index, 7 - 1);
index += offset;
/* valueArray[index] <--- first item in the combination */

offset = get_array_offset (24 - 2 - index, 7 - 2);
index += offset;
/* valueArray[index] <--- second item in the combination */

offset = get_array_offset (24 - 3 - index, 7 - 3);
index += offset;
/* valueArray[index] <--- third item in the combination */

... And so forth (fits nicely into a loop) ...
```

It's been a while since I have implemented such an algorithm.  The gist is there, but I may have an off-by-one error.  Similar logic can apply to permutation problems.

Hope this helps.