# How to generate all unique 4 character permutations of a seed string?

Tags: algorithm, set, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)
>   [Generate Distinct Combinations PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137880/generate-distinct-combinations-php)

I have an array containing a number of characters/letter,s e.g:

```
$seed = array('a','b','c','d','e','f',.....,'z','1','2','3',...'9');
```

I want to get all possible unique 4 character combinations/permutations from the seed, for example:

```
abcd, azxy, ag12, aaaa, etc
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I have thought about dividing the seed array into 4 letter groups, then go through each group and generate all possible combinations of that group, but that will leave out many combinations (i.e it will process abcd and wxyz, but not abyz and wxcd)

Comment: Do you mean combinations, or permutations?

Comment: @ninjagecko how would 4 characters be a permutation of 35?

Comment: @sehe: it's called k-permutation

Comment: @sehe: they could be permutations of 4-letter subsets of 35 (k-permutations).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, those questions are about different things than what I'm asking

Comment: @Click Upvote: just to translate the question.. is `aaaa` a valid output?

Comment: I.e in one question its asking about generating 5 combinations where each combo has 2 digits (so a total of 10 chars with 5 combos each), whereas im asking for 4 character combos, each combo like abcd, adcb, etc

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes, it would be

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Ok, you're looking for permutations, not combinations.  But the principle for generating them is very similar.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: He is not looking for permutations nor combinations. He is looking to get all possible combinations-with-replacement, or all elements of the 4th cartesian exponent of the set. He may or may not be considering them as sets or as ordered lists.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Is `abab` equivalent to `baba`?

Comment: @ninjagecko No. However I figured this out using my own algorithm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each character in the array, write that character followed by each of the unique 3 character strings either from the characters after it (if you actually mean combinations) or from all the characters (which is what I think you mean).

> How to generate all unique 3 character permutations of a seed string?

See [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404771/how-to-generate-all-unique-4-character-combinations-of-a-seed-string).

You may also want to read about [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

**Python code**

```
>>> def product(chars, n):
        if n == 0:
            yield ''
        else:
            for c in chars:
                for result in product(x, n - 1):  # Recursive call
                    yield c + result

>>> list(product(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2))
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
```

(Note: in real Python code you should use `itertools.product` rather than writing it yourself.)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question

Comment: @ClickUpvote: If this doesn't answer your question, then you need to clarify your question, because it answers what you've written.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth How does it answer the question 'how to generate unique permutations' by saying 'generate 3 unique permutations'. May be if he gives a code sample to clarify it, I might understand.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Because you missed that it implies a recursive solution.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I understood that he was trying to be witty/clever but it still doesn't answer my question in the manner its written.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: It's not really that clever, in fact it's quite explicit: to generate length-N permutations, you take each start letter in turn, and concatenate all possible length-(N-1) permutations.  This eventually hits a trivial base case.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Mate I'm not a computer whom you'll give a string like 'take each letter and concatenate all possible length N permutations` and I'll be able to compute it. How do I get all possible length N permutations? That's my question, if I'd known the answer to that I won't be asking this in the first place.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: With respect, this is a very simple concept, and you have 12k rep, implying that you're not a novice programmer.  It sounds like you're vying for someone to just give you the code, which I don't think is going to happen...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sometimes simple concepts are simple when you write them in code but they can be complicated when you write them in english. May be if you post an answer with some code doing what you're saying then I'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Anyway, as already pointed out, there are plenty of questions on SO already doing something very similar to what you want.  At least one of them must give you the relevant insight.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: How do you get all possible length 1 "permutations"? You can do that, right? OK, so now extend that to 2 letters by writing each letter followed by all the length 1 permutations. OK so far? Now extend that to 3 letters by writing each letter followed by all the length 2 permutations. Spot a pattern yet?

Answer (score 0):

Generating permutations is like summing up numbers. This is beautifully explained in the freely available book [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/), page 128